# Log deleted files to a text file

Tags: powershell

I want to know how to log the actions from this script to a text file because I don't know how to do it as the cmdlet `Start-Transcript` doesn't work for me and I wasn't able to find a solution on the Internet.

The problem is that the `Where-Object` cmdlet doesn't output anything captured by `Get-ChildItem`.

Does anybody has a good idea to solve this?

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)  
$path = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    !$_.PSIsContainer -and
    $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit
} | Remove-Item -Force

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
    $_.PSIsContainer -and
    (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {
        !$_.PSIsContainer
    }) -eq $null
} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse
```

Comment: What happens when you try to use Start-Transcript?

Comment: They would still need to add `-Verbose` to `Remove-Item`. Otherwise they'd have to run `Remove-Item` in a loop and log each successful deletion separately.

Comment: Start-Transcript only shows a date and an empty part where the actions of the commands should be, as far as I know Start-Transcript only shows the actions of commands typed by the user in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)  
$path =Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition

Get-ChildItem $path -file -recurse -force | where LastWriteTime -lt $limit | 
        Tee-Object -FilePath "c:\temp\deleted.txt"  -Append | Remove-Item

Get-ChildItem $path -directory | 
    where {(Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -file -Recurse | select -First 1) -eq $null} | 
        Tee-Object -FilePath "c:\temp\deleted.txt" -Append | Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 2):

howdy error666,

you can use use a few different methods ...

- `Tee-Object` = fork the stream to a file
- `-PipelineVariable` = accumulate the info in a variable
- use a loop  = put a log-to-file step in it
- put a `ForEach-Object` in the pipeline
  that can both log your info and do the `Remove-Item`.

the loop is the easiest to understand. [*grin*] however, if you want to keep it in a pipeline, you could add a `ForEach-Object` where the `Where-Object` scriptblock is and put both the filter test and the various actions in that block.

take care,
lee

Comment: The problem is that `where-object` doesn't give me any output, I can't display any result of this cmdlet on the console, save it to a string or write anything of it in a text file. I guess there is no way to avoid `where-object` because the `filter` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` only works for strings. (I'm new to Powershell scripting, so I don't know everything yet.)

Comment: @error666 - so replace the entire `Where-Object` with a `ForEach-Object` and put the tests in that. an IF will do the job. [*grin*] then save the to-be-removed item name to a log file. finally, remove the file. do all of that in the `ForEach-Object` block.